# PHP: is it posible to create two array with same name with two different dimension

Tags: php, arrays

Codeigniter PHP
I want to create two arrays with same name $name

```
$name = array();
$name[] = 'value';
$name[][] = 'value';
```

is this possible in any way because I am facing problem doing this?...

Comment: $name[] = array(); then you create another level

Comment: Remember, the variable name always unique. You can't set one variable in two times. Anyways, do you want to create a multi-dimensional array? can you please explain whole things

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Your question is unclear and likely to be closed in its current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is possible but you need to go about it in a slightly different way.

```
$name[] = ['value'];
```

Keep in mind that by doing this you're going to face the problem of accessing the array. You're probably better setting a key to make it easier.

```
$name['test'] = ['value'];
```

You can then append further values to your array quite easily.

```
$name['test'][] = 'second value';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, just use another index like below :

```
$name = array();
$name[] = 'value';
$name[]['array_2'] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as follows

1) One way

```
$name = array();
$name['first_key'][] = 'value';
$name['second_key'][] = 'value';
```

2) Other way

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
$final_array = array_merge($a1,$a2);
```